# XlsIo DateTime Incorrect by about 4 years

Tags: .net, excel

I'm using the XlsIo .net library and it seems to consistently return a date that is four years and one day in the past compared to the value I see in Excel.

Does anyone know what the cause of this is?

Comment: I've run into "out of date" technologies before, but that is ridiculous.

Comment: I wonder if the trial version of the library does it on purpose?

Comment: It sounds more like a totally screwed-up leap year correction, or something that worked great in XP and then died horribly in Vista. Ah, the perils of writing your own date/time code!

Comment: this is in Windows Server 2003

Comment: Could you show a few sample dates?

Comment: On a semi-related note, Excel Macintosh 2011 has the 1904 system turned on by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel has an option to use use the 1904 date system. This is turned off by default. I wonder if it is either on, or if the .net library is using that for it's calculation.

Comment: Yes, there's a property in the XLSIO library. Brilliant suggestion, thanks guitarthrower

Comment: So glad you posted this.  On a semi-related note, the Excel Macintosh 2011 has the 1904 system turned on by default.  This becomes a problem when you try to use any VBA dates whatsoever.  I found the setting in preferences and switched it off.  I lost hours on this problem, but would have lost even more without your help.  Once again, thanks for posting this!!